# Rocket League crashing as soon as I launch it

Tags: technical-issues, rocket-league, epic-games-launcher

I wanted to play Rocket League with my friends but everytime i try to launch it the game just crashes. I don't even make it to the title screen. I have all of the latest nVidia Game Ready drivers and have tried all of the steps on the Psyonix Support page. For further information, I'm on Epic Games and using an Acer Nitro AN515-51 with specs like this:

Intel Core i5 7300HQ
8GB DDR4 RAM
nVidia GeForce GTX 1050
Intel 256GB M.2 SSD

Update: Checked the Event Viewer and figured out that Rocket League complains about KERNELBASE.dll

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it?

Comment: I have tried reinstalling the game, even two times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My paging file was set to 0 MB due to a recent, very complicated hard drive upgrade. While launching, Rocket League did not have enough VRAM to actually get into the game, which was causing my issue. Setting the paging file to 5 GB fixed my problem.

Comment: Can you explain what this means and how this answers your question?

Comment: A pagefile partition is a partition on Windows used as VRAM, when it's set to 0 MB Rocket League can't use any of it, causing Rocket League to crash due to insufficient resources.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include your findings, and then mark it as the accepted answer for future users to refer to!

Comment: Sure thing! Just did that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately based on threads like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/q8l6ag/why_does_my_rl_crash_nonstop/), [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/q81j6y/game_crash_october_14_2021/), and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/q7fd1f/crash_on_startup/), this seems to be a bug introduced in the last update.  No one has found a workaround yet.

Comment: That sucks. What baffles me is that my friends on the same platform as I am are able to play normally, but I can't? What's even more baffling is that they have a worse PC than me.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the game icon and select the option'Run as Administrator' maybe it might happen.Or change compatibility mode.

Comment: I've tried that too, didn't change anything